# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<DistributionEmail.Data.EmailInfo>' to 'DistributionEmail.Data.EmailInfo'

Tags: entity-framework, blazor

I am writing my first blazor app to get certain email data and modify it if needed, aND i GET THE FOLLOWING ERROR OPN COMPILE.
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'DistributionEmail.Data.EmailInfo'

I have modeled my app on working examples I have found.
my class is

```
public class EmailInfoDb
{
    [Key]
    public int EmailInfoID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Address{ get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

The interface is as follows

```
 public interface IEmailInfoListService
 {
    Task<List<EmailInfoDb>> Get();

    Task<EmailInfoDb> Get(int id);

    Task<EmailInfoDb> Add(EmailInfoDb emailinfo);

    Task<EmailInfoDb> Update(EmailInfoDb emailinfo);
}

public class EmailInfoListService : IEmailInfoListService
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public EmailInfoListService(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<List<EmailInfoDb>> Get()
    {
         return await _context.Emails.ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task<EmailInfoDb> Get(int id)
    {
        var email = await _context.Emails.FindAsync(id);
        return email;
    }

    public async Task<EmailInfoDb> Add(EmailInfoDb email)
    {
        _context.Emails.Add(email);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return email;
    }

    public async Task<EmailInfoDb> Update(EmailInfoDb emailinfo)
    {
        _context.Entry(emailinfo).State = EntityState.Modified;
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return emailinfo;
    }
}
```

and finally, in the razor page I have

```
private void PrepareForEdit(EmailInfoDb task)
{
    customHeader = "Edit Task";
    emailObject = task;
}

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{

    emailObject = await EmailService.Get();

}

private async Task RefreshData()
{
    emailInfoList = await EmailService.Get();
}

private async void DataChanged()
{
    emailInfoList = await EmailService.Get();
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

The error only appears for the method

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    emailObject = await EmailService.Get();
}
```

Comment: On what line do you get the error?

Answer (score 0):

Well, your `EmailService.Get` method only returns either a `EmailInfo` instance or a `List<EmailInfo>` instance, but you're using it as if it returns both, look at this:

```cs
  protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {

        emailObject = await EmailService.Get();

    }
```

Here, you treat it as if it is a single `EmailInfo`, but here you (presumably, based on variable name) treat it as a list:

```cs
private async Task RefreshData()
    {
        emailInfoList = await EmailService.Get();
    }
```

So, your `OnInitializedAsync` method should look something like this:

```cs
  protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {

        emailObject = (await EmailService.Get())[0]; // get first EmailInfo instance

    }
```

Of course, this is a very naive implementation, you will want to check if the `List<EmailInfo>` you get from `EmailService.Get` is not null or empty, but assuming this is the only place you're using a collection of emails as a single instance, it should compile with this change.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately that answer does not solve my issue. I need to get a list of all the data, not just the first row.

Comment: @RickMorayniss Well, what do you have `emailObject` declared as? You need to make sure it is a `List<EmailInfo>`. I'm just assuming the types that you are using based on your variable names, and the compiler error you are getting is because you're trying to assign a List to a single `EmailInfo` object at some point in your code